# Fetch error using Apollo Client with the initiator createHttpLink.ts:185

Tags: reactjs, graphql, cors, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to use apollo client with graphQL to fetch data from a server that I do not have access too.

I was given an access token in order to be able to interact with the server.

I currently am getting a CORS error type:fetch Initiator:createHttpLink.ts:185

I have tried numerous ways to overcome this such as using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

below is my setup / call to API

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  createHttpLink,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: api,
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization:
        "Bearer token",
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_ALL_PROFILES = gql`
  query GetAllProfiles {
    profiles {
      id
      first_name
      last_name
      email
      is_verified
      image_url
      description
    }
  }
`;
```

```
import { Hidden, Button, Grid, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { PersonAdd } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { ViewWeek } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { List } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_ALL_PROFILES } from "../../graphQL/schemas";

// import GridCard from "./Card";

import "../../styles/grid/gridPage.scss";

const GridPage = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_PROFILES);

  if (loading) {
    return console.log("loading still");
  } else if (error) {
    return console.log("error still");
  } else {
    return console.log("Data", data);
  }
```